# What open source web programming languages are more restrictive than PHP?

Tags: language-agnostic

I learned some java first, and now I'm learning PHP.  I am not comfortable with how "free" it is, with things like loose typing.  I really liked the way java forces you into good practice.  Are there any open source web programming languages that are more restrictive than PHP, in the same way java is?

Comment: That certain languages "force" you into "good practice" is a myth. They only force morons to write more code to do the same damage. And at the same time, they restrict those who know what they do.

Comment: I'm a beginner, but I still have to puff out my chest and disagree with that.  As an example, going back to the loose typing thing, I am forced to specify what types a method will take as parameters and what types it will return in java.  Also, I can't make an array of Rhinocerous objects and then put a Kitten object in it.

Comment: @delnan aww, I think I see where you're coming from but that's a bit too harsh. I learned programming in Pascal/Delphi, but my daily work consists 99% of PHP these days. I *do* miss having a compiler that forces you to declare variables, use strict typing etc. I can understand the desire to work in a slightly more structured programming language, and it *is* possible to be forced into certain good practices - although that doesn't automatically make for good code, I agree there.

Comment: @lala: I'm not saying strict rules do only harm, they certainly help. But in practice, a static type system (your example...) is *too* strict in that it rejects code that would run perfectly well and *is* meaningful to a human reader; simply because the compiler (a machine) can't make sense of it. I really like C#'s approach to this topic: Static typing by default, but optional dynamicness.

Comment: @delnan, I'm sure you're right. I'm not here to argue about what type of language is best.  Just that I would prefer to work with a more strict language, and so I'm asking if one exists for the web.  Maybe after I have more experience, I will move on to less strict languages.

Comment: @Pekka: I can understand that, too, and I really like e.g. Haskell's type systen because it is very sophisticated (compared to e.g. Java or C#) - it doesn't get in my way, but it tells me when I screw up and write nonsense. As for "structured programming language" - again, strict rules make it easier, but a decent programmer's code will be structured anyway. The difference is that a more dynamic language is suitable for throwaway script *as well*.

Answer (score 3):

How about... Java? :D
If normal Java-driven frameworks are (for some reason) unacceptable, then how about [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html) - you write code in Java (with all the benefits of the language), but the application is compiled to JavaScript, which can be run on any modern browser. Additionally, it performs some optimization, etc - really worth looking into if you are familiar with Java and want to use that language to write "light" web applications.

---

If I didn't make it clear before: you *write* code in **Java** (you can use all the design patterns, object-oriented features, strict typing, etc., the compiler warns you if there are compilation-time errors, there's very mature Eclipse integration and so on), but the application is *compiled* to **JavaScript** - no need for Java plugin in the browser (no Java applets whatsoever). The compilation part additionally optimizes and obfuscates the output JS code so you'll get faster and smaller code, then if you wrote it by hand. **The server side is up to you** - while it is easiest to use Java there (especially with all the cool stuff coming in GWT 2.1), you easily use PHP, RoR or Django (via JSON or XML).

Comment: I read in various sources that Java applets are dead. Was I lied to?

Comment: @lala there is a difference between Java Applets that run in the browser (which indeed didn't take off the way it was envisioned), and Java as the server-side programming language (which is not dead at all)

Comment: Oh I see.  I'm a noob and didn't know the difference. Thanks.

Comment: @lala: added a clarification - hope that makes the whole thing clearer :)

Comment: @lala you're welcome. However, I'm not sure to what extent using GWT enables you to build full web applications. Server-side Java programming ([JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) and the likes) is what you should be looking into IMO